# Ограничения в DoCplex

Tags: python, модель

У меня есть линейная модель в docplex. Все переменные - continuous_var.
Дискретная модель мои объемы переменных и ограничений не тянет.
Возникла необходимость ввести новое ограничения в виде: X или равно 0 или больше 10.
Есть ли возможность ввести подобное ограничение не превращая модель в дискретную?
Пробовал применять binary_var и add_if_then. Это приводит к превращению модели в дискретную.